# django: limiting model instance based on foregin key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a models like these

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
   campaign_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
   user=models.ForeignKey(User)
   rows=models.IntegerField(default=3)
   columns=models.IntegerField(default=1)
   def __str__(self):                 # __unicode__ on Python 2
       return self.campaign_name+": "+self.campaign_desc

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print("Doing Custom Task ")
       super(Campaign, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.

class Item(models.Model):
   campaign=models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
   item_name=models.CharField(max_length=70)
   item_ID=models.CharField(max_length=400)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.item_name
```

I have registered Campaign in admin using `admin.site.register(Campaign,CampaignAdmin)` and want the number of items in each campaign to be rows X columns of campaign (Foreign key).

**Q1)** If I validate it using the save override method in the place of  `print("Doing Custom Task ")` , I couldn't save the instance when it's created.

**Q2)** It would be also nice to have the number of items to be filled to show up appropriately. Now I have

```
class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Item
   #extra = 4
```

in admin.py Basically I want the extra parameter to be rows X columns

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to do some custom validation, you'd better do it via forms, or (as a last resort), using the [`Model.clean*`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) methods family.

   ```
   class Campaign(models.Model):
       def clean(self):
           if self.pk:
               if self.item_set.count() > 5 # Or whatever number you need
                   raise ValidationError(_('Too much items for me.'))
   ```
2. Override the `get_extra()` method for your inline:

   ```
   class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):  
       extra = 4
       def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):           
           if obj:
               return obj.rows * obj.columns
           return self.extra
   ```

Comment: 1) How to check number of items associated with Campaign when the campaign or items are not saved yet.
2) some how obj is campaign. I don't know why. I'm getting 'Campaign' object has no attribute 'campaign'

Comment: 1) If a campaign is not yet saved, there are obviously no items associated with it (read - referring to this campaign's primary key). If you want to check the number of items associated with the already saved campaign, see the updated answer.
2) All the better in our case. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. You didn't understand my first question. I want to make sure the number of items the user enters is rows X columns. Even the first time.
2) This worked well.
 
          class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
             model = Item
             extra = 3
             def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):           
                   if obj:
                       if obj.rows * obj.columns>= obj.item_set.count():
                            return  obj.rows * obj.columns- obj.item_set.count()
                       return 0
                   return self.extra